# Type Checking in Hybrid Interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

This is an example as mentioned in the TypeScript handbook [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) -

> Hybrid Types
>
> As we mentioned earlier, interfaces can describe the rich types
>   present in real world JavaScript. Because of JavaScript’s dynamic and
>   flexible nature, you may occasionally encounter an object that works
>   as a combination of some of the types described above.
>
> One such example is an object that acts as both a function and an
>   object, with additional properties:

```
interface Counter {
    (start: number): string;
    interval: number;
    reset(): void;
}

function getCounter(): Counter {
    let counter = <Counter>function (start: number) { };
    counter.interval = 123;
    counter.reset = function () { };
    return counter;
}

let c = getCounter();
c(10);
c.reset();
c.interval = 5.0;
```

If I modify the type casting line in function getCounter to this, the compiler still verifies it as good.

```
let counter = <Counter>{ };
```

But if you run the compiled JavaScript, it will give error as *counter* is not really a function now but an Object.

Question - Should the TypeScript compiler give any error in this case or is it correct as a function is a sub type of an Object?

The link to editor is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Counter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(start%3A%20number)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interval%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reset()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getCounter()%3A%20Counter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20counter%20%3D%20%3CCounter%3E%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20counter.interval%20%3D%20123%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20counter.reset%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20counter%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20c%20%3D%20getCounter()%3B%0D%0Ac(10)%3B%0D%0Ac.reset()%3B%0D%0Ac.interval%20%3D%205.0%3B)

Comment: You can use `Object.assign` to create hybrid types without casting, e.g. `Object.assign(function (start: number) { ... }, { interval: 123, reset() {} })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `< >` operator is a forced type assertion/cast. You are telling the compiler to ignore everything it knows about the object, and to just assume it's the type which is specified inside the angle brackets. So from the Typescript compiler side everything is fine. Which means from usage side you should only fall back to those casts if you are absolutely sure that the type is correct.

More information in the **Type assertions** section here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 2):

Type assertions are used to tell the compiler to ignore the type it knows in favor of the type you tell it. If you are wrong about the assertion you make  the compiler cannot warn you about it. There are definitely types in Typescript when you will need to do this but if you can find a type safe way to do the equivalent it would be better. In this case you could use `Object.assign`:

```
function getCounter(): Counter {
    let counter = Object.assign(function (start: number) {  return ""}, {
        interval: 123,
        reset: function () { }
    });
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Event though we can use Object.assign to create a hybrid type, If we omit the 'function (start: number) { return "" }' definition, TypeScript won't give any error about a missing function. Is that expected?

Comment: Basically, in case of a Hybrid type, how does TypeScript ensures that a function for e.g. in question is provided and is not missing. 
function getCounter(): Counter {
    let counter = Object.assign({
        interval: 123,
        reset: function () { }
    });
    return counter;
}
This still compiles.

Comment: @ashish hm.. you got the only overload of assign where there is no error.. if you use an overload with 2 - 4 arguments, you get an error: `let counter = Object.assign({}, { interval: 123, reset: function () { } });`  Also you will get errors if the signature does not match :  `let counter = Object.assign(function() {}, { interval: 123, reset: function () { } });`. The `Object.assign` with a single argument will return `any` this is why it compiles